# Angular 4 Http req, get text body from HttpResponse

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, angular4-httpclient

I am working on an Angular 4 application using Spring Boot. Basically right now I have a service that upload a file from my Angular app to my Spring Boot server.

I want to print in the Angular logs the message from the `ResponseEntity` object that I receive from Spring, but I can't figure how to use the event object to get the message, here's my code sample:

**EDIT1:** `console.log(event.body)` prints well `message1` or `message2`, but I need to have `event.body` as a String to use it in a specific function.

Right now it is `HttpResponse<{}>.body: {}` but I don't know what it means in TS and how could I transform it to a String.

**EDIT2**: I think it should be like that

```
if(event.body instanceof String) function(event.body);
```

But I still get a type conflict between String and string. And modifying it to `string`, it says that 'string' is use as a value here.

UploadService:

```
uploadFile(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/post', formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Upload method:

```
 this.uploadService.uploadFile(file).subscribe(event => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            //Do some stuff
          } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            //message = event.body ?? //How to get message 1 or 2 below??? 
            console.log(message)
            });
            console.log('File ' + file.name + ' is completely uploaded!');
          }
        });
```

Here's the response from my Spring Boot server:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("message1");
```

or:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body("message2");
```

Comment: Did you *try* `event.body`? You can see the API docs for that object: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse.

Comment: Yes but event.body does not return me a String, and I need it as a String to use in a material snackbar later.

Comment: Well... what *does* it return? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I did some edits.

Comment: `new HttpRequest<string>(...)` - check the docs, they show you how to type the request.

Answer (score 0):

Using String constructor worked :

`String(event.body)` return me a `string` that I can use in my specific `function(string) :void`